# Filtering ajax input

Tags: javascript, ajax, input, filter

I'm building a front-end content editing module for my own framework using a WYSIWYG editor. All is going well except that the WYSIWYG editor uses html which includes & and =. When I try to submit this ajax will see it as another get or post var instead of 1 big var.

Now I could just fix this using .Replace to something and replacing it back server side, but I was hoping for a more standarized solution. Does anyone know of any?

Bottomline: I'm asking if there is a standarized method to filter input for ajax.

Code:

```
function submitData(content) 
{
    //Send it to save the edited content
    $.ajax({ url: 'index.php?ajaxCall=1&module=content&action=updateContent',
            type: "POST",
            data: "id=59&content=" + content.current,
            success: 
                function(result)
                {
                    alert(result);
                }
            });
}
```

Rob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are constructing your URI or POST body manually, you want [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

If you are using a helper library for Ajax, then you should probably be using that instead.

e.g. for jQuery:

```
{
    data: {
        myFieldName: stringOfHTML
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using jquery. But I don't get what you're refering to with your example. Could you please show me an example?

Comment: nvm, I can figure this out myself now. It's just a bitch to search for it on google etc. Thanks :)